# WPF password binding with passwordboxassistant through code

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to create a login screen but I want to do everything through code.

So generating the full UI through C#.

But I'm working with MVVM model and I have data binding on my username but this doesn't work on the standard PasswordBox so I found a namespace online which makes a workaround, it's called `PasswordBoxAssistant` from FunctionalFun.UI.

In the xaml I can create a passwordbox with the assistant but I'm making my UI through code and I'm not able to find how to use the PasswordBoxAssistant like that.

So I have this:

[image]

And want the same thing but in my C#:

[image]

But like you see in my code, I don't have access to it.

No idea if the xaml will only be to access it with everything is compile or why I can't use it in my C#.

Anybody that can help me implement this or point me to a direction?

Comment: Even if you have dynamic UI, the official advice is to create that using xaml strings.  XAML Is a markup language designed for the purpose of building wpf UI.  Why are you trying to do everything through code?

Comment: I'm pretty new to WPF and thought it would be easier to manage the UI through code. To have it more dynamic changing.

Comment: You should probably go with markup. Unless this is quite an unusual app.  What will be dynamic?

Comment: I don't know yet exactly how it will look like but I just thought it would be easier if I wanted to change something. My program will contain different screens but will for example always keep a menu bar at the top. But I will give it a try. But I'm still wondering what the solution would be in my main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems PasswordBoxAssistant is an attached property similar to PassWordHelper here:

https://gist.github.com/alamsal/fcefce4fb2d2d70fb2d91ee12741a35f

You attach such properties as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms749011(v=vs.100)#attached-properties-in-code

Hence something like

```
 PasswordBoxAssistant.SetBindPassword(yourPasswordBox, true);
```

Would add that to a variable yourPasswordBox.

You then need to create a binding on the BoundPassword dependency property of course.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-create-a-binding-in-code?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

The property you are binding as target is the PasswordBoxAssistant dependency property.

Bindings are a bit fiddly in code. I have used the approach rarely.

A rough example:

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
// myBinding.Source = ViewModel; Datacontext is default, you probably don't need source.
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("SomeStringPropertyInDatacontext");
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
yourPasswordBox.SetBinding(PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPasswordProperty, myBinding);
```

Comment: Is there another approach to have MVVM without data bindings? I'm trying your implementation that you mentioned.

Comment: Nope.  This code looks hard because you picked the hard way to do it.   MVVM transfers data between view and viewmodel using bindings. It's pretty fundamental.  I think you probably ought to watch some videos or something on wpf and mvvm.

Comment: I got it working. I'm checking a few videos about it, they just didn't mentioned anything when doing from the code. But I understand the concept that you explained.